# Disable android on-body detection suggestion

Tags: settings, security

Before the latest Android security update every time I have some form of Do Not Disturb on I get suggestions from Android to enable On-Body Detection. I click on the three dots and then it goes away - temporarily that is and it just keeps coming back.

Motorola Moto G4 - Noughat 7.0

[image: Image of settings]

Comment: You didn't​ even tell which phone model is that nor its android version

Comment: Sorry you are right. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here in the comments](https://www.androidexplained.com/nougat-remove-suggestions/) by Android Explained.

> You need to go into Google settings, activate on body detection and
>   then deactivate it again. Once that is done then you won't get
>   reminded about it anymore.

(This worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

This happens probably because you've set one of your device as trusted device. So, whenever the phone detects your body sensors, it prompts you this notification.

The feature is called [**Smart Lock**](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1105600). This automatically unlocks  your device when trusted places or devices have been detected, so you don't need to manually unlock your device.

You can disable it at ***Settings > Lock Screen and Security > Secure Lock Settings > Smart Lock***, then toggle it to Off.

[image: IMG:]